# Check if UITextfield is empty and display alert

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to prevent data from being saved and present an alert if any of the text fields are left empty. This is what I have, the alert pops up when I hit the save button, but the textfields are still saving with blank text when empty.

```
   // check if text feild is empty

    if usernameLabel.text == "" || passwordLabel.text == "" || phoneNumber.text == "" || service.text == "" || address.text == ""  {

        // Alert
        let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please Enter Text", preferredStyle: .Alert)

        // Add actions to the menu
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Cancel, handler:
            nil)
        optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

        // Display the menu
        self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


}   //End save button
```

Comment: have you written         if(usernameLabel .hasText() || passwordLabel .hasText())
        {
            
        }

Comment: is the save action written in else of this condition??

Comment: Off topic, but I wouldn't name a `UITextField` instance as "username**Label**" or "password**Label**"; if only to avoid confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you first remove the whitspace first because it also consider as character. So must remove whitespace use below code,

```
-(NSString *)remove_whitespace:(NSString *)string_data /* Remove whitspace in the string */
{
      NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
      string_data = [string_data stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespace];
      return string_data;
}
```

then , count the length of string. if it is greater than 0 go on, else popup error like below,

```
if([self remove_whitespace:textstring])
{
NSLog(@"work");
  }
else
{
NSLog(@"so error");
}
```

Got it?

Answer (score 1):

after your if end add return like this

```
if usernameLabel.text.length == 0 || passwordLabel.text.length == 0 || phoneNumber.text.length == 0 || service.text.length == 0 || address.text.length == 0  { 

    // your code 
    return
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but getting the same result. It is not stopping from saving blank text

Answer (score 1):

```
if(usernameLabel.text.characters.count == 0 || passwordLabel.text.characters.count == 0 || phoneNumber.text.characters.count == 0 || service.text.characters.count == 0 || address.text.characters.count == 0)  
{ 
    // your code 
    return
}
```

Use .characters.count for checking is checking textfield is blank or not.

Comment: I  tried this and I am getting an error, that .length is not of type string